# Want to pull all remote branches at once.. But git branch -r showing only some branches instead of 109 remote branches in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a remote repository from GitHub which is not mine. When I execute `git branch --all` or `git branch -r` it shows some branches instead of 109 branches. Same things happens when I use git `fetch --all` and `git pull --all` command. Those commands are not fetching and pulling all remote branches into my local repository. When execute `git remote show origin` it shows all remote branches. I want to pull all remote branches at once. I have also used one liner command for git bash, but not working also.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is there a pattern set up for the branches that are fetched? For example, a normal fetch line looks like this for a given remote: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` (that can be seen in `.git/config`

Comment: If you run `git ls-remote origin 'refs/heads/*'`, do you also see 109 branches ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, it shows all remote branches.

Answer (score 1):

The `--all` flag here means *all remotes*.  It is only meaningful if you have more than one remote (e.g., the initial `origin` plus your later addition of a remote named `upstream` or `repo2`).

The default for any clone is to copy *all commits* and *no branches at all*, because copying *branches* is generally not useful.  If you do copy branches, you often end up with the responsibility of updating them.  That's neither necessary nor fun, hence the default to copy *no* branches.  Instead, the normal setup is to take some other Git's *branch names* and turn those into *remote-tracking names* in your own clone.  A subsequent `git fetch` updates all the remote-tracking names, all automatically, so there is no need for you to have any branches at all.

Note that `git fetch` defaults to fetching from *one* remote.  For instance, if you are on branch `nurul` (see below) and have set its upstream to `origin/nurul`, this will fetch from only `origin`.  If you have set its upstream to `repo2/nurul`, this will fetch only from `repo2`.  (The upstream of a branch is usually the remote-tracking name in your own repository that corresponds to a branch name in the other Git repository.)  Should you want to update all `origin/*` *and* all `repo2/*` names, *now* `git fetch --all` makes sense.

If you wish to *create new commits of your own* in your repository, for whatever purposes—perhaps including sending these new commits to other Git repositories—*then and only then* does it make sense to create some branch or branches in your own repository.  The `git clone` command assumes that you probably do want to create one (1) new branch in your own repository, and will do that using the name you supply to the `-b` argument to `git clone`.

A branch name *must* select some commit.  The commit to select, when creating your own new branch, is sometimes the same as the commit named by some branch name in some other Git repository.  For instance, perhaps you might clone your co-workers' repository that has one branch for each co-worker plus one branch named `develop`.  The commits selected by each co-worker's branch names are not very important *unless* one of those is the commit you'd like to start with, in which case, you can use `-b coworker3` or whatever is appropriate here.  If the commit selected by the name `develop` is the most appropriate, though, you might use `-b develop` here.

In any case, now that you have a clone with one branch, your next step might be to rename your branch `nurul`, using `git branch -m nurul`.  Now your one branch has *your* name on it, so that you won't mix it up with any branches you create based on someone else's commit, should you want to add one commit just after their commit.

The actual work-flow you and your co-workers or colleagues will use is up to you, but it rarely makes sense to create a branch unless you plan to *add commits to that branch*.